# Is it acceptable to make a question by adding "or" at the end?

Tags: word-usage, british-english

Example:

"It is unacceptable for young ladies to put up their bare feet in public railway carriages, or?"

I only ask because the germans do it all the time as in:

"Ich habe dir schon einmal darum gebeten, oder?"
Literal translation - "I have already asked you once not to do it, or?"

and i find myself tempted to use the same form in denglish, excuse me english :-)

Comment: No, it is not common. What I have heard, is such as this:  "Are you trying to get yourself killed, or **what**?  "Is that an ugly dog, or **what**? It's a way of asking a question just to say that you can't imagine it could be anything other than what you suggested. (These are _rhetorical questions_; no reply is expected.)

Comment: Agreed - Note that adding "what" in that way makes for a very blunt and rather rude way of expressing oneself.

Comment: Kebten - It is incorrect. Not only that, I don't know what it means. Could you explain. What is the omitted part of the sentence that would come after "or" if it were written out explicitly? Thanks.

Comment: @Brian - yes true, but "or what" would be suited to more heated exchanges - to my ears it can sound aggressive. Does not "or" have a role in a more neutral exchange? May be the future ;-)

Comment: @chasly or could be substituted for example with "so what's your opinion" or "or am i being too inflexible?"

Comment: The context determines whether "or what" is aggressive.  "So, do you want to go to the movies , or what?"  "Is that apple pie, or what?"  Of course this is not formal, neither in writing nor in speaking.

Comment: @Kebten - The only way to make that work would be to say in full, "Or am I asking too much?"   I'm afraid there is no equivalent in English that I can think of that uses a shorter fixed phrase than that one.

Comment: @chasly - you don't think that extra questioning intonation on "or" would suffice as in: "Maybe its better to overlook the situation, or?"

Comment: @Kebten - No, I'm sorry. I don't see any way to make it work in English. You can try asking others if you like but I don't think the answer will be different.

Comment: @chasly voted your answer up based on your suggestion „or am i being too inflexible“ - it‘s obviously more long winded then simply ‚or‘ but fits perfectly. You can probably get away with just using ‚or‘ when speaking english with our european cousins but I agree the Queen and her land are for the moment not ready for such sub-clause compressions, or? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

It is incorrect in English and, speaking personally, I am uncertain what it means.

In English the 'or' sounds like a threat*, e.g.

"I have already asked you once not to do it, or [would you like me take some further and more drastic action to prevent you]?"

I don't think any native English speaker would know what you meant.

---

- Notice that this interpretation comes from the similarity with the English idiom "or else".

> or else   ...
>
> 2. Used to indicate negative consequences that will result if an action is not followed: We need to pay the bill, or else the
>      electricity will be shut off.
> 3. Used after a command or demand to make a threat: Be there on time, or else!
>
> http://www.thefreedictionary.com/or+else

Comment: Here's a similar example found just now "in the wild" on the internet:     'Not all agreement is herd mentality. Better to give people the benefit of the doubt, no?' Here "no" is being used like the "or" in my initial question. [from David C Dean, an american @ http://bryce.vc/post/3520840379/why-i-deleted-my-angellist-account]

Comment: Might be wrong about him being american..